# JNA - WriteProcessMemoryFloat (how write)

Tags: java, jna, kernel32

I need in JNA to write this method: **WriteProcessMemoryFloat**. In c# it's written like this
`[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "WriteProcessMemory")] 
     private static extern float WriteProcessMemoryFloat(int Handle, int Address, ref float Value, int Size, ref int BytesWritten);`
But in JNA I don't know how write EntryPoint. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to write a hack for a game. To write a float value using this yet: boolean WriteProcessMemory (hProcess Pointer, AdressToChange int, int [] ValuesToWrite, int nSize, IntByReference ignore), and adjusts the value of the float entry like this: Integer.parseInt (Integer.toHexString (Float.floatToRawIntBits (value )), 16), but I think it's too complicated